# Vue JS - lookup and retrieve details from json

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying trying to create small billing application but am getting stuck in  working on the cost Lookup. I went through the [vueJs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) but that didnt help much.

My piece of code is

```
    <tr><td><input type="text" v-model="prod0"></td><td><input type="number" v-model="qty0"></td><td>{{total0=cost0*qty0}}</td></tr>
```

What i exactly need is to read the product id that user enters in **prod0**, lookup and retrieve the cost of it from json.

My Json looks something like this.
{ "Mango":"100", "Tomato":80, "Carrot":"120" };

Would be really helpful if someone could provide me some JSfiddle/reference on
how to lookup a json, cross reference it and get the exact cost  by providing the product name.

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
{{total0 = products[prod0] * qty0}}
```

Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  data: {
    products: { Mango: 100, Tomato:80, Carrot: 120 },
    prod0: '',
    qty0: 0
  }
})
```

But I'd recommend to use computed property in this case, so your template will only need:

```
{{total}}
```

In your Vue instance, you can return 0 when there is no product matched:

```
computed: {
  total () {
    if (!this.products[this.prod0]) return 0
    return this.products[this.prod0] * this.qty0
  }
}
```

working example:
http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/JEGZgB?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks @CodinCat, that really helps  :) :)

Comment: I would like to use the same thing like a billing software. any chance if I can have the {{total}} value unique for each entry..
i mean, i would like to total1=prod1*qty1 , total2=prod2*qty2 and so on by looking up the json value for the products cost.. any suggestion for it please ?